# add properties to function in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript, still struggling in understanding what a function really is. From my understanding. an object in JS is like:

```
let person= {
 name: "Tom",
 age: 20,
};
```

and we can add properties as:

```
person.number = 1234
```

so the person object will be like:

```
{
  name: "Tom",
  age: 20,
  number: 1234
}
```

and now I have a function as:

```
function Person(name, age){
  this.name = name,
  this.age = age
}
```

below is my questions:

Q1.  when we add a new property as:

```
Person.number = 1234;
```

does it mean that JS will modify the Person function internally as

```
function Person(name, age){
  this.name = name,
  this.age = age,
  this.number = 1234
}
```

is my understanding correct, I can only think of this way, otherwise how could you add a new property to a function?

Answer (score 6):

No, `this` in `Person` is not `Person` itself, it's a (hidden) argument that is passed to it, just like `name` or `age`. When you add a property to the function itself, it doesn't affect `this` in any way.

```js
function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
Person.number = 1234;

console.log(new Person('Joe', 22)); // no "number" here
```

An exception of this rule is the special `prototype` property, which *does* affect `this` when you use the function as a constructor (`new ...()`):

```js
function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
Person.number = 1234;

console.log(new Person('Joe', 22)); // no "number"

Person.prototype = {number: 5678};

console.log(new Person('Joe', 22)); // has "number"!
```

Otherwise, a function is an object in javascript, and you can manipulate it like any other object.

```js
function foo() {}

Object.assign(foo, {'bar': 123, 'baz': 456});

console.log(foo.bar);
console.log(Object.keys(foo));
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

To clarify: `this` is a hidden argument which usually is an instance of `Person`, not `Person` itself, as in this case the code is following the JavaScript "class system" pattern.

Usually, when you see a function with arguments, accesing `this` and with the first letter as a capital one, is to define a "class" to instatiate it later with the `new` keyword.

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

var pepe = new Person("Pepe");
```

In the example above, I've created a `Person` instance and saved it to the variable `pepe`, so you can later do `pepe.name`.

When you use the `new` keyword is like creating a new object each time (with special properties) and running the `Person` function substituting the `this` value to the object that `new` created.

Well, then in this case the `this` variable inside `Person` function is the same instance as `pepe`, so you can create two instances and each one have a different `this`:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

var pepe = new Person("Pepe");
var manolo = new Person("Manolo");
```

In this case the `this` value will be the `pepe` instance in the first case and `manolo` when I run it the second time, so `pepe` is not the same as `manolo`.

So with this, if you access `Person.name` you are not accesing neither `pepe.name` or `manolo.name`, because `Person` is not an instance, but the "class".

As a small test, you can check that each time `new` is called, `Person` executes.

```
function Person(name) {
    console.log("Running Person with name", name);
    this.name = name;
}

var pepe = new Person("Pepe");
var manolo = new Person("Manolo");
```

To understand it better, they are two different objects. Is almost the same as having this:

```
var pepe = {
    name: "pepe"
};
var manolo = {
    name: "manolo"
};
```

In this case `pepe` is not the same as `manolo` because they are two different objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Person(name, age){
  this.name = name,
  this.age = age
}
```

This syntax is meant to be used as a 'class'. A blueprint of an object that you can make several copies of:

```js
function Person(name, age){
  this.name = name,
  this.age = age
}

let person_1 = new Person( 'John Doe', 42 );
let person_2 = new Person( 'Jane Doe', 24 );

console.log( person_1 );
console.log( person_2 );
```

This has the advantage that you can create a new Person object with only one line of code, instead of having to write:

```
let person_1 = {
 name: "John Doe",
 age: 42
};
let person_2 = {
 name: "Jane Doe",
 age: 24
};
```

Since you see that apart from the values, everything else in the object is the same.

It gets even better when you start adding functions to the 'blueprint':

```js
function Person(name, age){
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
Person.prototype.greet = function() {
  console.log( 'Hello, I am ' + this.name );
};

let person_1 = new Person( 'John Doe', 42 );
let person_2 = new Person( 'Jane Doe', 24 );

person_1.greet();
person_2.greet();
```

Both the Person objects now share the same function and you can refer to the actual person using the `this` keyword.

If you would do this with the two separate objects, you would get this:

```js
let person_1 = {
 name: "John Doe",
 age: 42,
 greet: function() {
  console.log( 'Hello, I am ' + this.name );
 }
};
let person_2 = {
 name: "Jane Doe",
 age: 24,
 greet: function() {
  console.log( 'Hello, I am ' + this.name );
 }
};

person_1.greet();
person_2.greet();
```

Even more repetition of the same code!

Now if we want to add the `number` property to the objects, we would have to do the following.

```js
// Add the number to the 'blueprint'
function Person(name, age, number){
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  // Save the number on our object
  this.number = number;
}

let person_1 = new Person( 'John Doe', 42, 7331 );
let person_2 = new Person( 'Jane Doe', 24, 1337 );

console.log( person_1 );
console.log( person_2 );
```

If you use `Person.number = 42`, then you would always have to use Person.number, it won't be available on any objects we create with the class:

```js
function Person(name, age){
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
Person.number = 1337;

let person_1 = new Person( 'John Doe', 42 );
let person_2 = new Person( 'Jane Doe', 24 );

console.log( person_1.number );
console.log( person_2.number );
console.log( Person.number );
```